# Specify directory location for external dependent jars in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

While making a new Eclipse plugin, how to I specify that all the dependent jars will be present in a specified location in the system(say: c:\product\ext). The main requirement is that these jar are not mine and I don't want to bundle them in my plugin and I plan to have some way to check for these jars and instantiate only if they are available at that location

TIA

Comment: Thus isn't really supported. You can specify external jars in a plugin's dependencies but they are hard to use and you can't stop the system trying to load them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you suggest me any good way to deal with such a situation.

Comment: Well you can always just use `URLClassLoader` to load classes - but classes loaded this way are awkward to use.